# plugins don't work with CKEditor 4.4

Tags: plugins, ckeditor

I am trying to add a plugin to CKeditor, so I followed this [tutorial](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_sample) which show you an example of a timestamp plugin which you can add to your ckeditor. this plugin example is available for download [here](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-docs-samples/tree/master/tutorial-timestamp)

I download it and it works pretty good with this configuration :

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {

    config.extraPlugins = 'timestamp';
}
```

html page :

```
<p id="editable-text" contenteditable="true"> 
    this is a text which should be edited by ckeditor
</p>

 <p id="another-editable" contenteditable="true"> 
    this is a text which should be edited by ckeditor
 </p

<script>
  CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
  CKEDITOR.inline( 'editable-text');
  CKEDITOR.inline( 'another-editable');
</script>
```

but after a while I was looking for a solution to share the toolbar between all the editable paragraph, and also fixed the toolbar's position on the top of the page. luckily I found a plugin called [sharedspace](http://ckeditor.com/addon/sharedspace) which do exactly that, I downloaded it and put it in the plugins folder then I added some lines to my config file to make it working.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {

    config.extraPlugins = 'timestamp';

    config.extraPlugins = 'sharedspace';
    config.removePlugins = 'floatingspace,resize';

    config.sharedSpaces = {
      top: 'toolbarLocation',
    }
}
```

Now the `timestamp` plugin is no more working. when I delete the few added lines the 'timestamp' plugin re-work (and I can see the timer button in the toolbar).

also **No other plugin** seems to work with the above lines of code.

Is there a way to solve that ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
    config.extraPlugins = 'timestamp';

    config.extraPlugins = 'sharedspace';
};
```

You first set `extraPlugins` to `'timestamp'` and right after that you set it to `'sharedspace'`. You need to set it once, with both values:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
    config.extraPlugins = 'timestamp,sharedspace';
};
```

Comment: I created a simplelink plugin and I want to "replace" the default "link", i did : config.removePlugins = 'link'; but it remove the "unlink" too. there is a way to stop ONLY "link" from triggering when double click a link ?